# Two scroll bars in Javascript dialog box

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code to open a url page in a javascript dialog. Everything is working fine but the issue is it gives two scroll bars which looks a bit odd [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvfBB.png). Can somebody help in removing it?

```
url = 'mypage.php'
var dlg=$('#div1').dialog({                  
    resizable: true,
    modal: true,
    hide: "puff",
    show : "slide",
    width:700,
    height:500
});
dlg.css({height:"500", overflow:"auto"})
dlg.html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + url  +'" width="100%"    height="100%"></iframe>');            
dlg.dialog('open');
```

Comment: overflow:"auto" : you need to remove that.

Comment: yes, set overflow on the `dlg.css()` to hidden, and set your iframe to `width: 100%; height: 100%;` just as you are doing. This should eliminate your double scroll bars.

Comment: when I  change it to overflow:"hidden" the scroll bar goes but when content of iFrame grows it's not displayed..

Answer (score 0):

Although I believe some of the comments have addressed the issue you're after, why not skip the trouble of loading the iFrame like that by taking advantage of the jQuery `.load()` function to directly port your `mypage.php` into your dialog like so?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // URL to Load
    url = 'mypage.php';

    // Set up Dialog Element
    var dlg=$('#div1').dialog({                  
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        hide: "puff",
        show : "slide",
        width:700,
        height:500
    });

    // Load Our Content
    dlg.load( url );   

    // Open Our Dialog         
    dlg.dialog('open');

</script>
```

Comment: Somehow load() does not work for me..I have hyperlink column in my table, when hyperlink is clicked, url open in dialog box. When I use load() it work only for first time when I click next time dialog box doesn't open